# How to detect end rendering event in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I draw the graph in D3.js. It has a lot of nodes and connections, so it take a while to draw in in D3.js.
I want to add the loading wheel until in render.
How can I detect when D3.js finish rendering?

Comment: If you use a D3 Force simulation, there is an `end` event... If it's something else, I'm afraid no notification is available

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I use D3v3 and I use force.start() with force.on("tick", updateNetwork), so svg.transition().each('end',  function(d){ console.log('end')  }) was called too early (until drawing was rendered)

Comment: There should be force.on('end', ...), not sure it's supported in V3

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky It works: force.on('end', ...) Many thanks for the help!